# Daily Sales from Total Sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that looks like this:

| ID | Sale_Date(YYYY-MM-DD) | Total_Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| 123 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 123 | 2022-01-03 | 5 |
| 456 | 2022-04-06 | 38 |
| 456 | 2022-04-07 | 40 |
| 456 | 2022-04-08 | 45 |

I want to get a daily sale column from Total Volume. which is just by subtracting the total volume on date x with total volume on date x-1 for each id.

| ID | Sale_Date(YYYY-MM-DD) | Total_Volume | Daily_Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 2022-01-02 | 2 | 2 |
| 123 | 2022-01-03 | 5 | 3 |
| 456 | 2022-04-06 | 38 | 38 |
| 456 | 2022-04-07 | 40 | 2 |
| 456 | 2022-04-08 | 45 | 5 |

My initial attempt was using a rank function and self join but that didnt turn out correct.

```
with x as (
    select 
        distinct t1.ID, 
        t1.Sale_Date, 
        t1.Total_volume, 
        rank() over (partition by ID order by Sale_Date) as ranker 
    from t t1 order by t1.Sale_Date) 

    select t2.ID, t2.ranker, t2.Sale_date, t1.Total_volume, t1.Total_volume - t2.Total_volume as Daily_sale
    from x t1, x t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.ranker = t1.ranker-1 order by t1.ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

- the [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function to retrieve last "*Sale_Date*" value
- the [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to replace NULL with "*Total Volume*" for each first rows

Then subtract `Total_Volume` from the previous value of `Total_Volume` and coalesce if the value of the `LAG` is NULL.

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE(`Total_Volume`
                -LAG(`Total_Volume`) OVER(PARTITION BY `ID` 
                                          ORDER     BY `Sale_Date(YYYY-MM-DD)`), `Total_Volume`) AS `Daily_Sale`
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yRXSpuYXHNhJHG96vxLEw/0).

Comment: Ahh didn't know there was a function that existed! Thanks! But how would you do it without using the function?

Comment: What function, LAG or COALESCE?

Comment: Without using LAG

Comment: Then you need to apply a self JOIN operation on `t1.Total_Volume = t2.Total_Volume -1 AND t1.ID = t2.ID`, though it's horribly inefficient, I wouldn't recommend that approach.

Comment: I see... but I'm wondering how would a self JOIN on`t1.Total_Volume = t2.Total_Volume -1 AND t1.ID = t2.ID`  make it work though?

Comment: Did you mean on `Sale_date` and not `Total_volume`?

Comment: Yeah, I meant "*Sale_date*", and applying the condition on a datediff/datedd computation is even more inefficient, as you can't use indices since you're computing the values in real time.

Comment: But then how do I get the correct Daily sale for the first day for each id? It would work for all days other than the first day if I were to do ```t2.Total_Volume - t1.Total_Volume as Daily_sale```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248879/discussion-between-lemon-and-hjun).